# understanding tcpdump udp output

Tags: udp, tcpdump

I'm getting the following output when I do a `tcpdump`

```
2017-07-26 00:00:00.062388 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 55135, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 78)
    192.168.1.69.26818 > 192.168.1.5.53: 8603+ AAAA? pkcba.ad.roy.com. (50)
2017-07-26 00:00:00.062859 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 7617, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 128)
    192.168.1.5.53 > 192.168.1.69.26818: 8603* 0/1/0 (100)
```

What do the numbers in the brackets `(50)` & `(100)` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case they're the length of the DNS payload within the UDP packet (note that they're 28 bytes less than the total packet length reported in the lines above - 20 bytes for a standard IP header without options and 8 bytes for UDP)

Comment: Thanks! Usually it says (length x) for payload length so I got a bit confused here

Comment: @pratikpncl NB: this is actually off topic here

Comment: what do you mean off topic?

Comment: I mean that it's not programming related.  Also, the info you requested is actually in the man page for `tcpdump` under "UDP Name Server Requests"